# jquery - cloned row loses functionality

Tags: jquery, clone, tablerow

**NEVERMIND.... I used live and it seems to work...**

I have table that contains form elements.  When a user enters a new value and clicks the add button, the last row of the table is cloned and the input fields are updated with the new information.  Additionally, each row contains a delete icon.  When the user clicks the delete icon, the row to which it belongs is removed.

I have all that working...

**Except**, the cloned row's delete icon doesn't work.  Nothing happens when you click it and I've tried various things, but can't seem to figure that part out... I just started using jquery like a month ago and think I'm missing something obvious, but not sure what...

I put the code on jsfiddle and am hoping someone can help out:

http://jsfiddle.net/sMqcB/

Comment: Don't use `.live`, use `.delegate`.

Comment: Just so you know, the `.live` is deprecated - you should use the `.delegate` method instead, as per @ExplosionPills comment above. Its ok to use `.live` if you can guarantee you're always going to be on a version of jQuery which supports it, but I suspect at some point you will want to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Because those are newly injected elements to the DOM. It wont know about the existing click event you already defined.

Solution: use jQuery's [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

Change

```
$('img.seminars-faux-remove').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

to

```
$(document).on("click",'img.seminars-faux-remove',function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

jQuery [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) will work for current and future elements. This method is available form jQuery 1.7+ onwards. If you are using an older version of jQuery, you may consider using [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/). But if you are using 1.7+ , you **should** use jQuery on.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the functionality by using `.clone(true)` instead of `.clone()`. See the [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) docs,and specifically the meaning of `[withDataAndEvents]` parameter.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sMqcB/4/)